# SP07 - WorkFlow where update ListItem

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, workflow, 2007, spfield

I want to create a workflow where update list item and increase with 1 her value.
This is for like, dislike functionality.

Like field is type number:
[image]

Where put a counter in workflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I remeber there is `Do Calculation` action in SharePoint Designer workflow 2007 :

So in this case ,

- Try to `calaculate the value of the current item filed "Like" plus 1` and set it to variable.
- Then update the list item with the output variable value.

**[Steps]**

```
Calculate CurrentItem:Like plus 1 (Output to Variable: result)
then Update item in Current item
```